# My name on the front page is not responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have written code for an animation in my name on my website's first page. I've used different h1 blocks for a single letter and the full name resides in a div block.
I wanted that on hovering on the letters of the name they raise up little bit and move upwards slightly, but I'm encountering a problem that on small screens instead of the whole last name a single letter goes down, if we go more small screen another letter then another, I wanted the whole last name goes down at once and forever.

I've tried keeping the letter in a same div block but the situation is same.
I expect that on a small screen the letter should not go down one by one but the full last name goes at once.

```css
.MainText {
  font-size: 50px;
  left: 18%;
  top: 25%;
  font-family: "Arial Black";
  position: fixed;
}

.hoverr {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  transition: top ease 1s;
  float: left;
  clear: none;
}

.hoverr:hover {
  top: -30px;
  transform: scale(1.15);
  text-shadow: rgb(121, 121, 121);
}
```

```html
<div class="MainText">
  <!--first name-->
  <div>
    <h1 class="hoverr ">A</h1>
    <h1 class="hoverr">B</h1>
    <h1 class="hoverr">H</h1>
    <h1 class="hoverr">I</h1>
    <h1 class="hoverr">N</h1>
    <h1 class="hoverr">N</h1>
  </div>

  <!--blank space for seprating first name and last name-->
  <h1 class="hoverr">&nbsp; </h1>

  <!--last name-->
  <div>
    <h1 class="hoverr">K</h1>
    <h1 class="hoverr">R</h1>
    <h1 class="hoverr">I</h1>
    <h1 class="hoverr">S</h1>
    <h1 class="hoverr">H</h1>
    <h1 class="hoverr">N</h1>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You can have only one h1 per page.

Comment: While I would suggest something like a `span` instead of `h1` for each letter, "You can have only one h1 per page" is incorrect, @Sfili_81

Comment: @SFili_81 you can have as much h1 tags as you want on a page, the only downside of this is that search engines may get confused and not index the page properly.

Comment: @Sfili_81 I can't find anything that says you can only have 1 h1 per page -- indeed, one of the first search results is https://www.seroundtable.com/google-h1-tags-23699.html

Comment: obviously it's bad practice for SEO.

Comment: @TomStock I'm a beginner and now not concerned much about SEO.

Comment: @Sfili_81 I'm a beginner and now not concerned much about SEO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a single h1 for your name and eventually vw to set your font-size:

example cleaning the html and a bit your css

```css
.MainText {
  font-size: calc(5vw);
  left: 18%;
  top: 25%;
  font-family: "Arial Black";
  position: fixed;
}

.hoverr {
  display:inline-block;
  transition: transform ease 1s;
}
.hoverr:hover {
  transform: scale(1.15) translatey(-3vw);
  text-shadow: rgb(121, 121, 121);
}
```

```html
<div class="MainText">
  <h1>
  <!--first name-->
    <span class="hoverr ">A</span>
    <span class="hoverr">B</span>
    <span class="hoverr">H</span>
    <span class="hoverr">I</span>
    <span class="hoverr">N</span>
    <span class="hoverr">N</span>
    <!--blank space for seprating first name and last name-->
    <br>
    <!--last name-->
    <span class="hoverr">K</span>
    <span class="hoverr">R</span>
    <span class="hoverr">I</span>
    <span class="hoverr">S</span>
    <span class="hoverr">H</span>
    <span class="hoverr">N</span>
  </h1>
  </div>
```

---

If there is nothing else on that page and that you want your name in the midlle, flex can easily help you for that :

```css
/* centers body in the window if smaller than window */

html {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

body {
  margin: auto;
}

/* end page centering */


.MainText {
  font-size: calc(5vw);
  font-family: "Arial Black";
}

.hoverr {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: transform ease 1s;
}

.hoverr:hover {
  transform: scale(1.15) translatey(-3vw);
  text-shadow: rgb(121, 121, 121);
}
```

```html
<div class="MainText">
  <h1>
    <!--first name-->
    <span class="hoverr ">A</span>
    <span class="hoverr">B</span>
    <span class="hoverr">H</span>
    <span class="hoverr">I</span>
    <span class="hoverr">N</span>
    <span class="hoverr">N</span>
    <!--blank space for seprating first name and last name-->
    <br>
    <!--last name-->
    <span class="hoverr">K</span>
    <span class="hoverr">R</span>
    <span class="hoverr">I</span>
    <span class="hoverr">S</span>
    <span class="hoverr">H</span>
    <span class="hoverr">N</span>
  </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For word/sentences that needs to "fill" a space instead of generating new lines I suggest [FitText](http://fittextjs.com/)

If you want implement it by yourself take a look at this:

```js
// For dynamic character count, you could do something like this:

  $('.fittext-dynamic').each(function(){
    let t          = $(this),
        width      = t.data("width") * 2,
        characters = t.html().length,
        size       = width/characters;
    
    $(this).css('font-size', `${size}vw`);
  });
```

```css
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baloo+Paaji';

.fittext {
  // to use, divide 100vw by letter count, including spaces
  font-size:8.8vw;
  line-height: 1;
  
  text-align:center;
}
.fittext2 {
  font-size: 5vw;
  margin-top: 0;
}
body {
  background-color:#c44032;
  color:#f4f1de;
  font-family: 'Baloo Paaji', 'Impact';
}
h1 {
   margin-bottom:0;
    text-align:center;
  text-shadow: #863027 .01em .01em 0,
   #863027 .02em .02em 0,
   #863027 .03em .03em 0,
   #863027 .04em .04em 0,
   #863027 .05em .05em 0,
   #863027 .06em .06em 0,
   #863027 .07em .07em 0,   
   #863027 .08em .08em 0,
   #863027 .09em .09em 0,
   #863027 .1em .1em 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="fittext">Fit me to browser width</h1>
<h1 class="fittext2">and me to half of it</h1>

<!-- The only thing that requires js -->
<h1 class="fittext-dynamic" data-width="100">and I'm dyamic!</h1>

<!-- Only necessary on document load, not window resize -->
```